# Deleting a specific Value from a linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, delete-operator

So this question might be a little odd but here goes.

I was having a problem with a function that searches an ordered linked list for a specific value and deletes the first node it encounters that contains the target value. The problem I was having is that it was throwing a Seg-fault whenever I passed it a value that wasn't on the linked list or tried to delete all copies of a target value by running it until it returned false (for "not found").

I solved the problem, but I don't quite understand *why* the change I made solved the problem I was having, as to me the methods seem equivalent. I've posted the "before and after" below, and I was wondering if more experienced eyes could give it a once over and explain why the change I made fixed the problem I described.

Before Fix:

```
bool deleteNode(Node *&headRef, int delVal)
{
    Node *delPtr; // for use in deletion
    Node *scan;   // "                        "
    Node *prev;   // "                        "

    if( headRef != nullptr ) {

        if( headRef->data == delVal ) {

            delPtr = headRef;
            headRef = headRef->next;
            delete delPtr;

        } else {

            scan = headRef->next;
            prev = headRef;

            while( scan != nullptr && scan->data != delVal ) {

                scan = scan->next;
                prev = prev->next;
            }

            if( scan->data == delVal ) {

                delPtr = scan;
                prev->next = delPtr->next;
                delete delPtr;

            } else return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

After (Changes have been marked):

```
bool deleteNode(Node *&headRef, int delVal)
{
    Node *delPtr; // for use in deletion
    Node *scan;   // "                        "
    Node *prev;   // "                        "

    if( headRef == nullptr )         // *CHANGE #1*
        return false;

    if( headRef->data == delVal ) {

        delPtr = headRef;
        headRef = headRef->next;
        delete delPtr;

    } else {

        scan = headRef->next;
        prev = headRef;

        while( scan != nullptr && scan->data != delVal ) {

            scan = scan->next;
            prev = prev->next;
        }

        if( scan != nullptr ) {      // *CHANGE #2*

            delPtr = scan;
            prev->next = delPtr->next;
            delete delPtr;

        } else return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
if(scan->data == delVal)
```

`scan` could be null, and you don't check; in the second version you check if it's null but not if the value matches the one you want to delete.  Maybe you want this?

```
if(scan != nullptr && scan->data == delVal)
```

Comment: Could well be, I guess I never thought that scan could both be null AND satisfy scan->data == delVal, but that seems to be the case.

Comment: It can't.  The point is that before you check `scan->data` you must check if `scan` is null.  Otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Ahhhh I got it; if scan is null, then scan->data is an illegal operation. I probably should have seen that... Thanks for clarifying!